# How to walkthrough "Movements" level?

Tags: from-dust

I'm stuck at second to last level in From Dust, called "Movements". The level takes place inside a volcano's crater with lava pouring in and constant flood of rains. Whenever I start colonizing totems the things get out of control very quickly. Either I get flooded or burnt.

How do I handle unusually harsh environments on the level and complete it?

Comment: Haha, This is where I stopped playing the game as well because of that level :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is going to be useful to anybody. These are the keys to the winning:

- Grab "Evaporate" totem and always cast it when it's about to rain, to avoid flooding
- Grab the "Lava protection" quickly
- Remove all the sand from below your totems to avoid fires (surprisingly it's okay to remove sand and have 0% vegetation)
- Later in game try to direct lava outside of the map by building walls from lava next to it's emitters

Answer (score 0):

Don't send your tribe till you have an area built. Use the plants to create dust by planting them then picking the dust around then replanting. Use the explosive trees to create a hole to drain water out of the mountain. Just near the tribe start is good.
Also try to rush for a different totem then the one you normally go to. Aquiring infinite earthbor jellify water will give you extra time.
Move the plants that will direct the lava to your tribe if they explode.
Runes will give you the ability to repel the lava or water(depending on the rune) if you can get your tribesmen to take the rune memory back to each totem. Have fun.